# Is there are a way to place any Onsen icon inside ons-button?

Tags: onsen-ui

I can't find anything in the documentation or on Google.

I tried looking in the following documentation:
https://onsen.io/reference/ons-button.html
https://onsen.io/reference/ons-icon.html

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for asking too-obvious question...
The answer is:

```
    <ons-button modifier="cta">
      <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" size="40px" fixed-width="true"></ons-icon>
    </ons-button>
```